# How to fix the height in !text using MapFishPrint?

Tags: mapfile, mapfish

How fix height in text block using MapFishPrint  config.yaml. For example in A4 size paper, my text change by content of ${content}.

My config.yaml

```
layouts:
  #===========================================================================
  A4 portrait:
  #===========================================================================
    mainPage:
      pageSize: A4
      landscape: true
      items:
        - !columns
          # columns can have an absolute position. In that case, they need a width.
          absoluteX: 30
          absoluteY: 565
          width: 790
          config:
            borderWidth: 0.3
            cells:
              - padding: 2
          items:
            - !map
              width: 788
              height: 543

        - !columns
          absoluteX: 600
          absoluteY: 565
          width: 220
          config:
            borderWidth: 0.3
          items:
            - !text                     != FIX HEIGHT OF ITEMS
              text: "${content}"
              backgroundColor: #FFFFFF
              fontSize: 12
              font: Helvetica-bold
        - !columns
          absoluteX: 30
          absoluteY: 100
          width: 100
          config:
            borderWidth: 0.3
          items:
            - !text
              text: "Loc"
              backgroundColor: #FFFFFF
              fontSize: 12
              font: Helvetica-bold
        - !columns
          absoluteX: 130
          absoluteY: 100
          width: 80
          config:
            borderWidth: 0.3
          items:
            - !text
              text: "IMG"
              backgroundColor: #FFFFFF
              fontSize: 12
              font: Helvetica-bold
        - !columns
          absoluteX: 210
          absoluteY: 100
          width: 400
          config:
            borderWidth: 0.3
          items:
            - !text
              text: "Titulo"
              backgroundColor: #FFFFFF
              fontSize: 12
              font: Helvetica-bold
        - !columns
          absoluteX: 130
          absoluteY: 50
          width: 150
          config:
            borderWidth: 0.3
          items:
            - !scalebar
              maxSize: 100
              type: bar_sub
              units: m
              vertAlign: middle
              barBgColor: #FFFFFF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the height in `!text` by setting the **`spacingAfter`** attribute.

Look how this works in my example:

```
- !text
  font: Helvetica
  fontSize: 40
  spacingAfter: 100
  align: center
  text: Example
```

[image]

```
- !text
  font: Helvetica
  fontSize: 40
  spacingAfter: 100
  align: center
  text: Example
```

[image]